# How to create custom Vary group in litespeed WordPress plugin?

Tags: wordpress, litespeed

I am trying to create custom Vary group (ESI) based on user capability instead of role in my wordpress website. Please help if anyone have solution to customize it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use other plugin , like role editor , to create different roles first , and then set them to different varies in ESI

Comment: I know, But I don't want to do that as I have thousands of user with multiple role. That's why I have asked a question.